# Mac Dictation and Dragon Dictate: which one has the highest speech recognition accuracy?

Tags: voice-dictation

Which one amongst [Mac Dictation](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT5449) and [Dragon Dictate](http://www.nuance.com/for-individuals/by-product/dragon-for-mac/dragon-dictate/index.htm) has the highest speech recognition accuracy for English?